# Windows Azure Connection

Tags: sql-server-2008, azure, virtual-machine, azure-connect

I'm trying to take my first steps with **Windows Azure** and i need to know if is possible to do what i need.

So, imagine the scenario that i've a **BD on my local machine** and i've a **VM (Win Server 2008 with SQL Server) in Microsoft Azure**.

I want to know is if is possible to **connect my local DB from my VM on Azure**.. 
i.e., Imagine that i need to implement **ETL processes** (Integration Services) on VM, **getting data from my local BD and load it on my VM DB**.

Is that possible?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.
you have to use either of:

- [Windows Azure Connect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg432997.aspx)
- [Windows Azure Virtual Network](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj156007.aspx)

to connect the Windows Azure VM to your on-premises network.
I'd suggest to start with Windows Azure Connect as it is fairly easy to install and configure. While the latter will require a hardware VPN/firewall router.

Also pay attention to the Name resolution scenarios - you have full support for name resolution with Windows Azure Connect, while you have to provide your own DNS to use with Windows Azure VN. Note that Windows Azure Connect however provides only IPv6 Connectivity. But with the name resolution in place named pipes protocol shall be fine.

**UPDATE**

You can only download Windows Azure Connect from the old silverlight portal (http://windows.azure.com/). You can navigate to the old portal from upper right corner -> click on your login id, a drop down menu will appear, select "Previous portal" (the first option). Then follow the tutorials. Once you create your Azure Connect Groups, you will have the option "Download Azure Connect Agent". It is custom download per subscription, that's why there is no public download for it:

[image: Get the Azure Connect]

Comment: I've been following tutorials and download links for "Windows Azure Connect" all around the web, and without fail, they take me to old information.  I absolutely cannot find a download link for "Windows Azure Connect".  Even that link you provided in your answer doesn't actually take you to any downloads.  Could you send me a URL that lets me download "Windows Azure Connect"?

Comment: Thanks a lot.. I will try it.. 
So, the first approach is easiest than Windows Azure Virtual Network but it is only available on old portal, is this synonimous that it will be discontinued ?

Comment: I haven't heard such rumor (discontinuing Azure Connect), but will not be surprised if that happen.